# Visual Studio Code 2020 - git connection and adding a project

Tags: javascript, java, git, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code. I have a local project and want to add to a new repository in Git.

Can some one share ref docs or steps for the same.

want to update Repo connection setting , initialize the project `git init` and add it to repo

[image]

```
Version: 1.44.2 (user setup)
Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
Date: 2020-04-16T16:36:23.138Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal

If Git:

```
git clone https://${repoUrl}
git status
git add .
git status
git commit -m "added new files to repo"
git push
```

if Bit Bucket:

```
git remote add origin https://${repoUrl}
git push -u origin master
```